What should my name be on research articles?
Kamiruzzaman is my name. Although the last five letters zaman are typically used as a surname, my academic records all use the name Kamiruzzaman. However, I've been having trouble lately submitting research articles to various journals because they require my first and last names, mandatorily — I don't know how to respond.
I'm considering separating Kamiruzzaman into Kamiruz and Zaman as respective first and last names. Would it be an issue if I kept this separation for all of my research articles because my academic certifications will bear the name Kamiruzzaman?

Falsehoods programmers believe about names (apparently, journal editors too)

Sometimes a period '.' is used as dummy for a nonexistent entry.

What about "Kamiruzzaman Zaman"?

@CaptainEmacs: It's also common to use NLN (no last name) as an entry in such systems, since many systems won't tolerate a non-text placeholder entry.  Either approach seems more likely to cause future headaches than the advice offered in answers (hence why this is not posted as an answer).

If it feels right to you you could consider making up a first name and listing Kamiruzzaman as your last name. This has the advantage that you'll be cited as (Kamiruzzaman, 2024), and you're unlikely to get confused with other people called Zaman.

@gerrit While this is pretty funny, it would help a lot more to give examples and ways to deal with this. I mean, in very many countries people have some kind of official name on their birth certificate, passport, driver's license etc. And this name is surely written in the characters of some language, which are almost surely represented in unicode.

@N.Virgo Doesn't even need to be a full first name. I occasionally see "X" listed as the middle initial for people who don't have one. (Whether a fake name or fake abbreviation, this ensures that your real name does occur somewhere in the database, which splitting it up would prevent.) Also, consider that the name on the submission form probably isn't the one people will see: the one you put on the paper is. Alternately, if that name does get displayed somewhere, perhaps the first name of "Dr." would serve.

@JFabianMeier A version with examples.  How to deal with it?  Programming a form with less input restrictions is less work than more input restrictions.  But this becomes off-topic on Academia.SE.

@gerrit Thanks! Actually, for the first two weeks of my life, I did not have a given name as well...

You can use any name for publication purposes that you like as long as it doesn't involve fraud or misrepresentation. You can't be Albert Einstein unless you have some actual claim on that name.
Your solution of splitting your name into two parts is fine, but you should also get an ORCID identifier and use it and your name choice consistently throughout your career.
There are too many issues about names, mostly driven by incorrect assumptions, to list. The assumption, is that people have exactly three names and the given name is listed first, the family name last, and the one in the middle optional. This is globally false, but too many systems are built that way. Go to Hungary, or most places in Asia, or places where some fraction of the population has many, many separate "words" in a name, including honorifics. My spouse's "first" name is two words. In the old days, before computer algorithms messed it up this was not a problem. Her birth certificate and her passport correctly give her name, which has four separate words. But every other computerized system, even doctor's offices tend to get it wrong.
Ideally, your name should be presented as you choose to present it (with some restrictions, perhaps). That is to say, that systems should be designed to permit your publication name to be Kamiruzzaman if you choose that.
People change their names, also. This can be a problem for academics, just as "non standard" names are. I have some interest in changing my own IRL name (back to my birth name) but can't/won't for various personal and professional reasons.
I think there are lots of people in the world that have a single name and, within their culture, it is perfectly normal. Even some show business superstars have taken to using a single name.
But an ORCID, tagged to any publication will point to you. And you can provide, on a website, the linkage between your "publication name" and your IRL name if you like.
I think this problem will continue until those sites requesting names and intending to later display them, ask the individual for specific guidance (tags, perhaps) to guide the system. Imagine that "John Doe" is actually "family-name(John), given-name(Doe)".
I've also just noticed that there isn't even a universal agreement about how to "capitalize" names, assuming even that such is a meaningful question. bel hooks, for example, though that was a personally chosen pen name.
For a view of the complexity in naming see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name

This so much! Even with a classic western name I was stunned how many systems are utterly incapable of handling a change of family name. An ORCID is absolutely worth the minor effort it takes to set up.

Just a note: Even the assumption many would have, that having a single name is a non-western or “exotic” thing, is wrong. Most European rulers had and have one single name, such as Queen Elizabeth.

@Neinstein Nitpick: Queen Elizabeth had three names, but these were all given names.

@rexkogitans Nitpick. Queen Elizabeth II had three forenames (Elizabeth Alexandra Mary) and one surname (Windsor): see her death certificate https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Queen_Elizabeth_Death_Certificate.webp

Indeed, Prince Harry was "Harry Wales" while in the army. So if it's any consolation to the OP and it's them and the royal family that have the same problem :-D

@erstwhileeditor (I am not sure, but) I am afraid that the surname on her death certificate is an example where a "falsehood of programmers" got materialized.

@rexkogitans AIUI "Windsor" is the royal families' surname/family name.  It used to be "Saxe-Coburg and Gotha" but was changed after the first world war because of anti-German sentiment in the U.K. at the time.  It is arguably closer to conforming to the "falsehood of programmers" now than it was at the time.  Their names (excluding titles) are fairly canonical for the U.K. (having more than one middle name is not that unusual, e.g. Mrs Marsupial).

@rexkogitans This is not any old death certificate: this one is issued by the Registrar-General. Her father is also given the surname Windsor, and this in a free text box, it's not a requirement to enter something. I agree it was not always so!

For a more exhaustive summary of all the ways our assumptions about names are wrong:  https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

I’m a researcher with a single name, so here’s my approach. My full name is “Harshvardhan,” and I don’t have a last name on any legal documents. For publications, I use the name “M Harshvardhan”—though technically, I could choose anything reasonable. I put my name as the last name so that it can be cited as Harshvardhan et al. (20xx) if needed. I also attach my ORCID to all publications whenever possible.
I’ve noticed that Google Scholar sometimes doesn’t pick up my articles automatically, but this isn’t an issue as I can manually add them. I also have a post on my website explaining this situation in detail. When asked, I usually give a one-line explanation (“I don’t have a last name”) and share the link to my blog. So far, this approach has worked smoothly in academic circles.
Another tip: on Google Scholar, you have the option to say multiple names. Utilize that to add your publication name as well. Here's mine for example:

For government documents, however, things can vary. For example, my EU visa lists my name as “Harshvardhan Harshvardhan,” while in the U.S., it appears as “FNU Harshvardhan.” For official documents, it’s essential to follow each country’s guidelines, which you can ask/search beforehand. But for academic publications, you can choose a format and stick with it throughout your career.

FNU is an abbreviation used by the U.S. government system. It means "First Name Unknown". See for example https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-errors/name-appears-as-fnu/

How did you choose "M"? Just curious.

M is the first letter of my family name.

@Harshvardhan If you have a family name, why do you say your full name is only "Harshvardhan"? I'm genuinely curious because I definitely don't claim to know how every naming system works.

@Azor Ahai -him In the interest of brevity, I'll suggest checking the blogpost where I answer it in detail! https://arc.net/l/quote/yqvbqper

I read it, thanks for sharing! I'm still not sure where "M" comes from, though.

@AzorAhai-him- A family name ("Modi" for me) is not always used like last name. E.g., at a wedding, we would be called "Modi Family" but all my family members use different or no last names. Family name is often related to caste in India but that's also not always true.

Gotcha thanks! .

'Kamiruz Zaman' should be fine.  It is best to publish only under that one name.  If there are no papers by 'Kamiruzzaman', then there will be no confusion for references.  It will be unimportant that your academic credential reads 'Kamiruzzaman'

If you can present your name in a format that is both recognised by the system and relatively consistent with your academic records then you should be fine. It will be obvious to any human looking at your records that the name Kamiruzzaman is the same as the name Kamiruz Zaman.
Many people end up with their name formatted slightly differently between different journals anyway - for example using a middle initial which is sometimes expanded into the full name.

An automated search however might be unlikely to turn up a paper if the search was for "Zaman".

It will be obvious to any human looking at your records that the name Kamiruzzaman is the same as the name Kamiruz Zaman. [citation needed]

@WoJ i argue that it is not, in fact, obvious even to humans. it is very common for me to stumble on articles with this exact issue, and where i can't be certain that this is what's happening. I of course suspect it is, but it could also be a coincidence.

Fair points! I meant more in the context of when you need to show your academic credentials to someone in particular - e.g. in the context of a job application - it is a small enough change that it's obviously the same name when you explain it. In comparison to someone like me who has changed their first name by deed poll and needs to produce additional documents to prove I'm the same person.

You can use "NFN" as your first name, it stands for "No First Name". Teller, of the magic duo Penn & Teller, uses this as his first name on official government documents like his driver's license.

Actually, with a single name there is a question as to whether it is the "first" or "last" name that is missing. And, of course "first" and "last" has no universal meaning.

I think it's simply a common convention to treat single names as surnames (which is the generic term that avoids "first" and "last" issues).

Somehow I doubt that. It would mean that siblings would have different surnames.

That does happen. Consider Russian, where female and male surnames are different.

That is a different idea. Many conventions use something like a gender indicating suffix. But even in those cultures brothers, then, would have different "surnames". Likewise sisters.

In iceland siblings also have different surnames based on gender.

@Barmar The male and female surnames differ in many Slavic languages and also in Icelandic. As Buffy mentioned, these suffixes are gender-indicative. While the root of the surnames remains the same, the suffix changes to reflect gender. Therefore, they are considered the same surname, even though they are not the same word.
